# Alert if dynamic checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I have a dynamic checkboxes that are ticked if the user wants to delete a certain row. Now what I want is an alert that will say "Are you sure you want to delete?" if any one of the checkboxes are checked and "Nothing selected!" if non of the checkboxes are selected. This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<th><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="<?php echo $row_direct['id']; ?>"></input></th>
```

Script:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var $delete = jQuery.noConflict();

$delete(document).ready(function(){

    $delete(".delete").click(function(e){

        if (document.getElementsByName('select[]').checked == false){
            alert('nothing is checked');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        else {
        if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

What's happening is that I only get the "Are you sure you want to delete?" alert no matter if a checkbox is checked or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [`$(ELEMENT).is(':checked')`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) ?

Comment: Hi @Darren. Tried, if ($delete('select[]').is(':checked')  == false){}. Doesn't work.

Comment: And also, why are you closing your input element with `</input>` ? The `<input>` tag is self-closing and doesn't require that.

Comment: @user3724238 `$delete('[name="select\\[\\]"]').is(':checked')`

Comment: Oooh. Noob mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($delete('[name="select[]"]:checked').length > 0) {
  alert('Are you sure?');
} else {
  alert('Nothing checked');
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the answer. Just fix the typo in your `if` block. (*one too many `)`*).

Answer (score 0):

The `.checked` on the `getElementsByName` function does not work because `getElementsByName` returns an array of elements. This should work:

```
if (document.getElementsByName('select[]')[0].checked == false){ ...
```

However, since you have jQuery loaded Aguardientico has a nicer solution for you.

Comment: He also seems to be using more than one checkbox, so checking the first instance of it could still cause issues.

Comment: Well, in the case that there are two inputs with the same name, even a jQuery selector would not make sense as it is not clear which element will be used to do the operation on. If you are going to select by something in a selector and you expect only one element, better be sure you are only selecting one element!

Comment: That is more than a valid point. Although if you look at the OP's code, you'd see that he 'requires' at least one check-box to be ticked.

Comment: Yes indeed and that is where the selector by Aguardientico does what the getElementsByName selector can't.